# Store the newly opened tab URL in local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am trying to open a new tab from an existing tab and want to store the newly opened tab link in the local storage. Using below JS but i dont see it storing anything in local. The idea was to do a callback once the tab has loaded.

```
function openAndSetUrl(tabName, callback) {
  var newWindow = window.open("https://google.com", tabName);
  
  if (newWindow) {
    newWindow.onload = function() {
      var url = newWindow.location.href;
     localStorage.setItem(tabName, url);
      if (typeof callback === 'function') {
        callback(url);
      }
    }
  }
}
  
  function openInNewTab(tabName) {
     openAndSetUrl(tabName, function(url) {
  console.log("URL set to:", url);
});
}
```

Comment: I imagine this might run into problems if you're attempting to open a URL on a different domain, I can't say for certain but that feels like something that might be locked down for security reasons.

Comment: Definitely if you're going to open `https://google.com`

Comment: I gave google as just an example. But the idea is to open tabs of the same origin

Comment: You said that the value wasn’t set in localstorage but you need to do additional debugging. Add logging system to see which bits of the code do get called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the new window is on the same origin, the following should work:

```js
newWindow.addEventListener('load', ev => {
  const url = ev.target.documentURI;
  localStorage.setItem(tabName, url);
  if (typeof callback === 'function') {
    callback(url);
  }
});
```

Comment: Edit: grabbing the location from the event target (document) instead of accessing `window.location`, which didn't seem to work.

Comment: This works, thanks!. But just wondering,  why would newWindow.onload not work and add vent listener works? How both of them are different?